# Display Item in dropdown based on Radio button selection

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, radio-button

I want to display particular items in my dropdown based on the selected radio button by the user.

The two choices are Financial Alteration and Non-Financial Alteration. So if I select the Financial Alteration Radio Button. The drop-down just displays me the values below financial Alteration.

**Here is the Code**

```
       <div class="col-sm-2">
                                                        <div class="form-group m-0 m-b-15">
                                                            <label>Type of Alteration Request</label>
                                                            <div class="radio radio-custom m-t-5">
                                                                <input type="radio" name="q3" value="1" id="5a">
                                                                <label for="5a">
                                                                    Financial
                                                                </label>
                                                                <input type="radio" name="q3" value="1" id="5b"
                                                                    style="margin-left: 30px;">
                                                                <label for="5b" style="margin-left: 30px;">
                                                                    Non-Financial
                                                                </label>

                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>



                                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                        <div class="form-group m-0 m-b-15">
                                                            <label for="textfield" class="control-label">Endorsement
                                                                Type</label>

                                                            <div class="controls controls-row">
                                                                <select class="form-control" data-rule-required="true"
                                                                    id="EndorsementType" name="EndorsementType">
                                                                    <option value="">-- Non-Financial Alterations --</option>

                                                                    <option value="Add/ Remove Exclusion">Add/ Remove Exclusion</option>
                                                                    <option value="Add/ Remove/ Update Beneficiary / Nominee ">Add/ Remove/ Update Beneficiary / Nominee </option>
                                                                    <option value="Address Change ( Correspondence )/ (Permanent)/ (Business)"> Address Change ( Correspondence )/ (Permanent)/ (Business)</option>
                                                                    <option value="Change In Correspondence Flag ">Change In Correspondence Flag </option>
                                                                    <option value="NIC Change ">NIC Change </option>
                                                                    <option value="Client Name Change ">Client Name Change   </option>
                                                                    <option value="Duplicate Policy Schedule">Duplicate Policy Schedule</option>
                                                                    <option value="Change in Guardian">Change in Guardian</option>
                                                                    <option value="Client misc data change"> Client misc data change</option>
                                                                    <option value="Change in occupation"> Change in occupation</option>
                                                                    <option value="Change in Height/Weight"> Change in Height/Weight</option>
                                                                    <option value="Change in phone number"> Change in phone number</option>
                                                                    <option value="Account number updated "> Account number updated </option>
                                                                    <option value="Change in email address"> Change in email address</option>
                                                                    <option value="Policy assignmnent"> Policy assignmnent</option>
                                                                    <option value="Change mail to address"> Change mail to address</option>
                                                                    <option value="Change in health status/hazard">Change in health status/hazard</option>
                                                                 
<!--FInancial Alterations-->
                                                                        <option value="">-- Financial Alterations --</option>

                                                                        <option value="Addition/ Deletion Of Riders ">Addition/ Deletion Of Riders </option>
                                                                        <option value="Mode Change (Small To Big) / (Big to Small)">Mode Change (Small To Big) / (Big to Small) </option>
                                                                        <option value="Premium De-Allocation "> Premium De-Allocation </option>
                                                                        <option value="Premium Increase/ Decrease">Premium Increase/ Decrease </option>
                                                                        <option value="Sum Assured Decreased/ Increase ">Sum Assured Decreased/ Increase </option>
                                                                        <option value="Agent Change">Agent Change  </option>
                                                                        <option value="Cancel Policy - Company Initiated ">Cancel Policy - Company Initiated </option>
                                                                        <option value="Policy Cancelled On Client Request">Policy Cancelled On Client Request</option>
                                                                        <option value="Policy Surrender"> Policy Surrender</option>
                                                                        <option value="Partial Surrender "> Partial Surrender </option>
                                                                        <option value="Reinstatement Entry - Individual ">Reinstatement Entry - Individual </option>
                                                                        <option value="Unit Movement"> Unit Movement</option>
                                                                        <option value="Benefit term increase/decrease "> Benefit term increase/decrease</option>
                                                                        <option value="Gender correction"> Gender correction</option>
                                                                        <option value="Esclatation rate change /Growth Rate change "> Esclatation rate change /Growth Rate change </option>
                                                                        <option value="Add/remove extra mortality"> Add/remove extra mortality</option>
                                                                        <option value="Change fund distribution">Change fund distribution</option>
                                                                        <option value="Adjustment in NAV"> Adjustment in NAV</option>
                                                                        <option value="Special/Extra special reinstatement "> Special/Extra special reinstatement </option>
                                                                        <option value="Commencement Date Change ">Commencement Date Change </option>
                                                                        <option value="Plan Conversion"> Plan Conversion</option>
                                                                        <option value="Client Date Of Birth Change (Financial)  "> Client Date Of Birth Change (Financial) </option>
                                                                        <option value="Adhoc Surrender"> Adhoc Surrender</option>
                                                                        <option value="Matuarity "> Matuarity</option>
                                                                        <option value="Renewals/Lapse"> Renewals/Lapse</option>
                                                                        <option value="ANF/Paid UP">ANF/Paid UP</option>





                                                                </select>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made an example for you here.
The example is basically the following steps:

1. Mark up your HTML

   ```
   <input type="radio" name="group" value="1" checked />
   <label>Radio 2</label>
   <input type="radio" name="group" value="2" />
   <label>Radio 3</label>
   <input type="radio" name="group" value="3" />

   <div>
     <select id="drop1">
       <option>DropDown 1</option>
     </select>
     <select id="drop2" class="no-display">
       <option>DropDown 2</option>
     </select>
     <select id="drop3" class="no-display">
       <option>DropDown 3</option>
     </select>
   </div>
   ```
2. Add CSS

   `.no-display {display: none;}`
3. Add event listeners to the radio buttons that call your drop-down selecting function

   ```
   for (var i = 0; i < radio_buttons.length; i++) {
       radio_buttons[i].addEventListener("change", setDropDown);
   }

   function setDropDown() {
       setDropDownsForNoDisplay();
       if (this.checked) {
           setDropDownForDisplay(this.value);        
       }
   }
   ```
4. Add helper functions that the drop-down selecting function uses

   ```
   function setDropDownsForNoDisplay() {
       for (var i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
           dropdowns[i].classList.add("no-display");
       }
   }

   function setDropDownForDisplay(x) {
       if (x === "1") {
           document.getElementById("drop1").classList.remove("no-display");
       } else if (x === "2") {
           document.getElementById("drop2").classList.remove("no-display");
       } else if (x === "3") {
           document.getElementById("drop3").classList.remove("no-display");
       }
   }
   ```

You could also use events ("onclick", "onchange") directly in the radio button markup instead of adding event listeners, but I prefer keeping my events separated from the markup.

Here is Snippet Run:

```js
var radio_buttons = document.getElementsByName("group");

for (var i = 0; i < radio_buttons.length; i++) {
    radio_buttons[i].addEventListener("change", setDropDown);
}

function setDropDown() {
    setDropDownsForNoDisplay();
    if (this.checked) {
        setDropDownForDisplay(this.value);        
    }
}

var dropdowns = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
function setDropDownsForNoDisplay() {
    for (var i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
        dropdowns[i].classList.add("no-display");
    }
}

function setDropDownForDisplay(x) {
    if (x === "1") {
        document.getElementById("drop1").classList.remove("no-display");
    } else if (x === "2") {
        document.getElementById("drop2").classList.remove("no-display");
    } else if (x === "3") {
        document.getElementById("drop3").classList.remove("no-display");
    }
}
```

```css
.no-display {display: none;}
```

```html
<label>Radio 1</label>
<input type="radio" name="group" value="1" checked />
<label>Radio 2</label>
<input type="radio" name="group" value="2" />
<label>Radio 3</label>
<input type="radio" name="group" value="3" />

<div>
  <select id="drop1">
    <option>DropDown 1</option>
  </select>
  <select id="drop2" class="no-display">
    <option>DropDown 2</option>
  </select>
  <select id="drop3" class="no-display">
    <option>DropDown 3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: You're welcome, because in your case need a javascript for processing your radio showing a Dropdown